# How do I replace a dash and new-line?

Tags: regex

How do I replace a dash (`-`) and bring up the next line? See the following sample text and desired outcome:

**Sample text:**

```
abbr, benefit, continue, re-
vive, raisin, nuts
```

**Output text:**

```
abbr, benefit, continue, revive, raisin, nuts
```

Comment: Who on earth voted for this question to be closed for being **too broad**? This is a very clear and simple question...

Comment: @scrowler Simple: the OP didn't provide any code/info on what he/she has tried. Don't feed the helpvampire.

Comment: I agree it should be closed - but this question doesn't fit the description for "too broad" at all.

Comment: @scrowler My guess is that it's a pain to choose the appropriate close reason since there is no close reason that bluntly states we expect some efforts. So closers tend to choose whatever reason. I tend to choose for `unclear what you're asking` or a custom close reason for this type of questions: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues.`

Comment: Much better! Too broad is pointless here. [Whoever voted it should read this.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262842/2812842)

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues.

Answer (score 3):

Search: `-[\r\n]+`

Replace: empty string

- `-` matches the hyphen
- `[\r\n]+` matches one or more chars that are a carriage return or a linefeed
- we replace that with an empty string, bringing the two lines together

Comment: @scrowler, thank you for being fair. There's some human beings who are deeply evil but excellent in finding faults to stand in others' way.